# "tx" array inside blocks contains transactions hashes?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, hash

When I use the "getblock " command on my bitcoin core client, it returns, beside other things, an array called "tx" with hundreds of hashes. Are these the individual transactions hashes or something else? If they are really transactions hashes, does the client keep the unhashed transactions in other structure and do I access it through other command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the fine manual!

> $ ./src/bitcoin-cli help getblock
>   getblock "blockhash" ( verbosity )
>
> If verbosity is 0, returns a string that is serialized, hex-encoded data for block 'hash'.
>
> If verbosity is 1, returns an Object with information about block .
>
> If verbosity is 2, returns an Object with information about block  and information about each transaction.

So if you add a `2` to the end of the RPC request, you'll get the full transaction contents rather than just the hash.